# Saving image without compressing

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, unix

I know that JPG, BMP, GIF and others formats compress image. But can I get snapshot of display and save it without compressing(in binary file) in programming way (using c/c++ for example or other stuff)?

Comment: Is lossless compression OK? PNG is good for lossless for typical screenshots (big areas of constant colour) and there are free libraries for dealing with it. In C, for example, you'd probably use libpng and zlib. As Kevin says, BMP is the obvious choice if you don't want compression. TIFF has a huge range of options, including uncompressed - one of the problems with TIFF files is that some applications with TIFF support can't read all possible TIFF files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BMP files aren't compressed by default.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 2):

http://www.zlib.net is your best solution for loss-less compression in C. It's well-maintained, used in a host of different software and compatible with external archivers such as winzip.

C++ offers wrappers around it such as boost::iostreams::zlib and boost::iostreams::gzip.
Zlib uses the deflate algorithm (RFC1951); here a very good explanation of the algorithm: http://www.zlib.net/feldspar.html

Answer (score 0):

The [PAM format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAM_graphics_format) is uncompressed and really simple to understand.